# Mapping Lists from 2 lists flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, fluttermap

sample of Options that i have:
[image: sample 2]

I have 2 List, the first one is named options:

```
List<String> _options = [
    'Arts & entertainment',
    'Biographies & memoirs',
    ...
  ];
```

and the other name _isOptionSelected:

```
List<bool> _isOptionSelected = [
    false,
    false,
    ..
  ];
```

**im trying to generat a map form those 2 list.**

what i have tryed is this:

```
 Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>> _isOptionMap = {
      'Arts & entertainment': {
        'optionName': 'Arts & entertainment',
        'isOptionSelected': false,
      },
      'Biographies & memoirs': {
        'optionName': 'Biographies & memoirs',
        'isOptionSelected': false,
      },

      ..
    };
```

and then print it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _isChoiceChipSelected.length; i++) {
      _isOptionMap[_options[i]]['isOptionSelected'].update(
          _options[i],
          (value) => _isOptionMap[_options[i]]
              ['isOptionSelected']);
    }
    print(_isOptionMap);
```

Is a logical problem? and what im I doing wong ?

Comment: Hello @Hussain the question is not clear enough. What have you tried and what is the result you get? What is the expected result?

Comment: im trying to create a map, 

i have a list of Options<String> 

and a list of selectedOptions<bool> that is set initially to false. 

what im trying to do is create a map from those 2 list.

Comment: let's say the user taps on THAT chip, THAT chip value should be changed to true in the _selectedOptions List<bool>. i have done this part already.

Comment: now from those 2 list's, im trying to create a Map that looks like this.
  { 'Arts & entertainment': {
        'optionName': 'Arts & entertainment',
        'isOptionSelected': false,
      },
...
}

Comment: and why not a map like: `{'Arts & entertainment': false, 'Biographies & memoirs': true}` ?

Comment: your right! this way it will be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello this code creates a map like the one you want.

Be aware that "_options" and "_isOptionSelected" lists must have the same lenght.

```
void main() {
  List<String> _options = [
    'Arts & entertainment',
    'Biographies & memoirs',
  ];
  
  List<bool> _isOptionSelected = [
    false,
    false,
  ];
  
  Map m = {};
  
  _options.asMap().entries.forEach((entry) {
    int idx = entry.key;
    String val = entry.value;
    
    Map m1 = {
      'optionName': val,
      'isOptionSelected': _isOptionSelected[idx]
    };
    
    m[val] = m1;
  });
    
  print( m );
}
```